# Find completely non-distinct rows

Tags: oracle, distinct

I have an Oracle table I've compiled using an Informatica workflow. It's failing an integrity check because the following queries return a different number of rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table // 4,000 rows
SELECT * FROM table // 4,006 rows
```

The table consists of 17 fields, none of which are unique keys (obviously). How can I find the 6 duplicate rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For returning duplicate rows.

```
  select * from 
    (SELECT cd.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY column1,column2...column2
                  ORDER BY column_names)
               seq_no
       FROM table cd)
    where seq_no>1;
```

For example i have create one sample_table below for your better understanding.

```
create table sample_table
(
id1 number,
id2 number
)
```

i have inserted below data into table

```
 ID1    ID2
    1   2
    1   2
    1   2
    2   3
    2   3
    2   3
```

In above data set we have  6 rows but only two rows are distinct.
By using below queries we can get distinct rows and non-distinct rows.

```
    SELECT cd.*,
                ROW_NUMBER ()
                OVER (PARTITION BY id1
                      ORDER BY id1)
                   seq_no
           FROM sample_table cd
```

after partition the table with the help of id1 we will get the below results

```
ID1 ID2 SEQ_NO
1   2   1
1   2   2
1   2   3
2   3   1
2   3   2
2   3   3
```

Then if you want to see the distinct rows use below query

```
select * from 
    (SELECT cd.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id1
                  ORDER BY id1)
               seq_no
       FROM sample_table cd)
    where seq_no=1;
```

if you want to see duplicate set use below query

```
select * from 
    (SELECT cd.*,
            ROW_NUMBER ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id1
                  ORDER BY id1)
               seq_no
       FROM sample_table cd)
    where seq_no>1;
```

Comment: That query returns zero rows.

Comment: Ok i understood the problem, why it is not returning rows we have to use partition clause i will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

A posibiliy is to use a analytical function to count the rows in the same group and I don't see how you can write the query without writing all the columns in some clause:

```
select * 
from (
   Select a.*, count(*) over (partition by column1, column2, ..., column17) as cnt
   from your_table a
)
where cnt>1
```

This should get 12 rows, because 6 are duplicated.

A basic sql query would be:

```
select  col1, col2, ..., col17
from table
group by col1, col2, ..., col17
having count(*) > 1;
```